# How to create an executable notebook in Mac OS X

Tags: front-end, bugs, mac-os-x, scripting

All,

I am looking for help to create a notebook to be executed via terminal in MAC OSX. The notebook uses the front end.

This is what I have so far

```
#!/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/Mathematica -script

UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate["/Users/MyFolder/MyFile.nb"]]
```

When I run the script in snow leopard Mathematica opens a new notebook containing the above code displayed in quotes, when run in lion I get a window saying the notebook cannot be opened.

I will be very grateful to anyone who can point me in the right direction as to how to proceed.

Many thanks

Comment: I think this really is a bug. So my answer can be seen as a workaround, but I've been using it for so long that I never noticed the problem you encountered with the `UsingFrontEnd` approach. When I tried your example, I get a Terminal message saying that `CFURLCreateWithString` was passed an invalid string.

Comment: I noticed that too, looks like a cocoa error.

Comment: @Christina I had more success using a slightly different #! line to yours...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I do is the following.

Save the following code as a text file in a permanent location under the name `MathematicaLauncher.scpt`:

```
tell application "System Events"
 try
    get process "Mathematica"
    on error -- Not running, launch and run
       launch application "Mathematica"
              -- May need to wait until application finishes launching
                 repeat while "Mathematica" is not in name of processes
                              delay 0.5
                                    end repeat
                                    end try
end tell
tell application "Mathematica"
 activate
 do script "notebook0=NotebookOpen[\"~/MyFile.nb\"];Clear[notebook0];NotebookClose[EvaluationNotebook[]]"
end tell
```

On the last line before `end tell`, replace the name and path of `MyFile.nb` with the location of your actual *Mathematica* notebook, of course!

Now from the Terminal, just type

```
osascript MathematicaLauncher.scpt
```

and the notebook will open. If you want to do additional things after opening the notebook, add the corresponding notebook manipulation commands after `NotebookOpen[\"~/MyFile.nb\"];`.

As an additional layer, you can now save the `osascript` terminal command in a `shell` script if needed - for example:

```
#!/bin/sh
osascript MathematicaLauncher.scpt
```

Save this in the same directory as the `scpt` file and make it executable, and you're done.

**Explanation**

The launcher is written in `AppleScript`, and the reason I do this is so that I have more flexibility of doing other things in addition to launching the notebook. What the script does is to create a temporary `notebook0` from which the target notebook `MyFile.nb` is opened. After opening it, you can for example add additional lines to `MyFile.nb` before evaluating it. That can be done using `SelectionMove` and `NotebookWrite`.

In particular, you just wanted to evaluate your notebook. In that case you'd put your command `NotebookEvaluate[\"~/MyFile.nb\"];` in the string following `do script`.

**More info**

As mentioned in the comments, you have to first start *Mathematica* normally by clicking on the Application, and disable the splash screen that appears at startup by default. It blocks execution of the script that `AppleScript` is trying to send it. That screen is the first thing I disable whenever I get a new version of *Mathematica*, so I almost forgot it exists.

Other than that, I've been using this method to launch and manipulate notebooks almost every day without problems, across updates to both *Mathematica* and OS X.
I actually prefer to save the `AppleScript` not as a shell script but as an Application using `AppleScript Editor`, because then I can put its icon in the dock and launch the process with a mouse click. So instead of saving the script at the top in a text file, you could paste it into `AppleScript Editor` and go from there.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, it never occurred to me to write an AppleScript. I'm having a little trouble however, I get an error error, '"Mathematica got an error: Connection is invalid." number -609', and Mathematica quits. Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, that happens if Mathematica tries to show the startup-screen - the small modeless window with the various "What do you want to do" options. It seems to wait for user input and prevents the script from being executed. For this method to work,  you have to disable that screen by un-checking the box on the lower right of the start-up screen.

Comment: Superb! Works perfectly. Many thanks.

Comment: Great - I just added the bug tag to your question because I think your original approach shouldn't have produced an error.

Comment: Does any one know if this still works for the current version  Mathematica 12.2 on OSX Majove and upward?

Answer (score 5):

It works OK for me here on Mac OS X Mountain Lion, *Mathematica* 9, given a few minor changes:

***Mathematica* Script saved as math-script.math:**

```bsh
#!/Applications/Mathematica.app/Contents/MacOS/MathematicaScript -script

Print["loading"]
UsingFrontEnd[NotebookEvaluate["/tmp/test-notebook.nb"]]
Print["quitting"]
Quit[]
```

***Mathematica* Notebook saved as /tmp/test-notebook.nb**

```
p = Plot[{Sin[x]}, {x, 0, 2 Pi},
       Epilog -> {Text[DateList[], {5, 1}]},
       PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
Export["/tmp/plot.png", p];
```

**Running the script:**

```
 $ date
 Thu 27 Dec 2012 22:34:57 GMT
 $ ./math-script.math 
 "loading"
 "quitting"
 $
```

The result:

[image: simple plot]

Perhaps the contents of your notebook are causing problems...

Comment: I can only test it on version 8 under OS X Lion currently, and there the script hangs, even though two *Mathematica* kernels start running. It prints only the "loading" part, and no other output (neither in terminal or *Mathematica*). Anyway, +1 just for the prospect that the future will be brighter...

Comment: And the hanging is not due to any error in the `test-notebook.nb` (I removed the legend for compatibility)...

Comment: Update: with version 9 of *Mathematica*, this does work under OS X Lion.

Comment: @Jens - nice to know they fixed a bug! :)

Comment: @Jens--to explain further: the Mathematica executable is the FrontEnd executable; it doesn't read from standard input and is not scriptable.  You wanted either MathKernel or (better yet) MathematicaScript, as expalined here.

Comment: I took Jens' approach and it worked great for Mathematica 8 on OS X Snowleopard, however, with Mathematica 8 on Lion, when I run using osascript through terminal I get a Mathematica window "could not find or open notebook" though it works perfectly when run from the AppleScript editor. Should this be posted as a separate question?