# How to open Mathematica from the terminal in OS X

Tags: mac-os-x, notebooks

So far, when I was working in Linux, I would open my *Mathematica* files from the terminal by typing:

```
mathematica filename.nb &
```

But now, I got a mac, and when I try it says

```
-bash: mathematica: command not found
```

So, I have to open the *Mathematica* files by going to Finder and double clicking the file in a Finder window, which is annoying!

I tried to google it, and I expected that it would be easy to find info about it, but I did not find any.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Related: [How to create an executable notebook in Mac OS X](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/17006/245)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might give this a try:

```
open filename.nb
```

Comment: indeed, it works :)))! Thankyou zoo much!!

Comment: And for reference, if that doesn't work, try: `open -a Mathematica filename.nb`.

Comment: And how can I open a new notebook, i.e. not an already existing file from the terminal? In Linux it would be just "mathematica &"

Comment: @Mencia `open -a Mathematica`

Comment: @ Michael E2, I tried it but, it does not open a new one but it opens the last file I was in.

Comment: @Mencia `open -n -a Mathematica` opens a new instance of Mathematica. `touch ${TMPDIR}/new.nb; open -a Mathematica ${TMPDIR}/new.nb` creates a new file in a temporary folder and then opens it. Since the file is created inside the temporary directory it will be removed when the system is restarted. I think the equivalent to what you're talking about is the first option, but it opens the splash screen instead of a blank notebook.

Comment: thats what I was looking for, thanks a lot @Pickett !!

Comment: @Mencia To create a new notebook, just switch to Mathematica (or start it up) and press Command-N.